# Ascending working but Descending not working python

Tags: python

```
Lower = (input ("Give lower limit: "))
Upper = (input ("Give upper limit: "))
Lower = int(Lower)
Upper = int(Upper)
X = input ("Ascending order (yes/no): ")
if X == 'yes':
    for number in range(Lower,Upper+1):
        print(number)
if X == 'no':
    for number in range(Lower,Upper,-1):
        print(number)
```

The ascending part is working but numbers are not printed when X == 'no'

Comment: You're asking a range from `Lower` to `Upper`. For reverse, you need to swap them: `range(Upper, Lower, -1)`, otherwise you'll define an empty range (which is why nothing is printed)

Answer (score 1):

Your second loop is reversed, try the following:

```
Lower = (input ("Give lower limit: "))
Upper = (input ("Give upper limit: "))
Lower = int(Lower)
Upper = int(Upper)
X = input ("Ascending order (yes/no): ")
if X == 'yes':
    for number in range(Lower,Upper+1):
        print(number)
if X == 'no':
    for number in range(Upper,Lower,-1):
        print(number)
```

Also if you also need to print `Lower` you need to change to `range(Upper,Lower-1,-1)`

Answer (score 0):

You have been miss leading by list indexing.

[Range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) can takes three arguments, *Start*, *Stop*, *Step*. Step, contrary to indexing with negative number, do not start your iteration as reverse but only increment the start  value.

- Start is inclusive, default is 0
- Stop is exclusive, so if you want to see it, you should add to your stop number, the step you want, this is the only variable needed.
- Step, by default is 1.

```py
Lower = int(input ("Give lower limit: ")) 
Upper = int(input ("Give upper limit: "))
X = input("Ascending order (yes/no): ").lower()
if X == 'yes': 
    for number in range(Lower,Upper+1):  
        print(number) 
if X == 'no': 
    for number in range(Upper,Lower - 1,-1):   
        print(number)
```

Imagine you want to print number from 1 to 5.

### Ascending

```py
>>> for i in range(1,6,1): #note, step of 1 is the dafault value
...    print(i) 
1
2
3
4
5
```

### Descending

```py
>>> for i in range(5,0,-1):
...    print(i) 
5
4
3
2
1
```